# What is the purpose of `Function.prototype.future`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am looking at [fibers/future](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). I am wondering what the purpose of `Function.prototype.future` is in this case. I have tried a few experiments.

```
let Future = require('fibers/future');
let socket = require('net').connect(process.env.connection);

waitForMessage = function (message) {
  let future = new Future();

  let listen = function (fut, data) {
    let match = new RegExp(`^${message}$`);
    if (match.test(data.toString('ascii'))) {
      fut.return();
    }
  }
  socket.addListener('data', listen.bind(this, future));
  future.resolve(future, () => {
    socket.removeListener('data', listen.bind(this, future));
  });
  return future;
}

waitForOkay = function (msg) {
  waitForMessage('OK').wait();
}.future();
```

I have a vague understanding of how it's meant to be used... but what does it actually do? When should it be used?

Comment: Take a look at this, it is explained quite well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: Are you asking specifically for your code, or generally for the feature in the node-fibers package?